# Can Failover Clustering in WIndows be set-up on Google Compute?

Tags: failovercluster, google-compute-engine

My understanding is that a Windows Failover Cluster node must be multihomed and that GCE Instances cannot be multihomed.

Is this the case, please?

Comment: Hey Daniel, you can open a feature request for this on Google Compute Engine public issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list

Comment: Also, take a look at this articles for some tips: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/robustsystems
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/target-pools#add_or_remove_a_backup_target_pool
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/disaster-recovery-cookbook#application-recovery

Comment: For those of us who don't know Windows could you expand your question with an explanation of what exactly multihomed means in the context of Windows Failover Cluster?

Comment: If you are running MySQL on Windows servers, it is possible to configure the failover cluster manager as described in here, this might help in your case.